# Using 'new SomeObject' in custom attributes

Tags: c#, attributes, constructor, parameter-passing, custom-attributes

I'm using custom attributes in my game to allow me to define dependencies between aggregated components.

`[ComponentDependency(typeof(SomeDependentComponent))]`
`class SomeComponent : Component {}`

However, this means I have to use default values for every component I want to add this way. I would like to be able to do:

`[ComponentDependency(typeof(SomeDependentComponent), ctrParam1, ctrParam2...)]`

And feed these directly into `Activator.CreateInstance(Type, object[])`, but I get errors. I think it's to do with attributes being compile time. I don't know much about them.

Is this possible?

EDIT: If I were to use parameters, it may look like:
`[ComponentDependency(typeof(PositionalComponent), new Vector2(300, 300))]`

Comment: What would the parameters be?

Comment: It sounds like you would be better off using a Dependency Injection container like NInject or Autofac for this kind of thing rather than trying to write your own.

Comment: @mdm Currently looking up Ninject and it seems to make sense..sort of.

Comment: I feel this would probably be a new question, but I do not see how DI would be beneficial here..I can **just** about understand the concept, but I don't see how it links into here. I'm sure it does, but I just don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Attributes are compiled to metadata in the assembly.
Attribute parameters can only be primitives or `Type` objects.

Comment: That's a shame. Ah well, shall have to just implement a load of default values. A way to do something like this would be neat, though.

Answer (score 1):

As SLaks says, this won't work.  What you are trying to build is called "Dependency Injection" which is a powerful and increasingly popular pattern.  There are many Dependency Injection frameworks built for .NET - I suggest doing some research on them and choosing one - they have mechanisms (usually XML config files) to handle what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've done a little googling on DI and roughly understand it..but how would it apply to my situation?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change parameters of attributes, because they are compiled and stored in the assembly metadata.

You might implement an interface on your components e.g. IDependantComponent and call SetDependencies after it's created.